# How jpa achieves schema independence

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am a beginner to jpa and hibernate, I understood that how jpa achieves database independence and persistence provider independence.

I came across the sentence which states

```
jpa can achieve schema independence
```

how does jpa achieves this?

Comment: you "came across the sentence" ... care to tell us where, and what it is supposed to mean?

Answer (score 0):

JPA is an API, this API is completely abstracted from your data representation and DDL. Also, it is abstracted from the API implementation (unlike going directly for Hibernate).

This means that you can:

- Use differing JPA implementations such as Hibernate or Toplink
- Use different DB dialects such as Oracle, T-SQL, PostgreSQL
- Implement your own JPA implementation

These can be done through annotations *AND/OR* configuration. So in theory you can switch from Oracle to PostgreSQL without having to recompile your application.

This also means you can do other funky things like:

- Use a free, Open Source DB for development, and then Oracle/SQL Server for Production
- Use Hypersonic for automated tests, so everything is in memory and torn down automatically.
- Use other data-sources such as XML transparently.

You get other niceties like SQL injection protection out of the box, very quick startup time (rather than having to code everything twice), automatic DDL generation when you've defined your entities etc. which get small projects started quicker than the traditional route.

IN REALITY:

- Nobody chooses to go from Hibernate to Toplink
- Very few people ever implement JPA for a project
- Very few people rapidly switch DB backends as each Database performs very differently
- Also, the differing dialects can drive out weird bugs.

The configuration aspects and the ability to use things like Hypersonic are useful though.

The other "flip side" to the lovely API abstraction is that the implementation can be too constraining, resulting in very inefficient SQL being produced. This ends up with the developer having to add in native SQL anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanation but still the question is unanswered about schema independence? There can be many schema's on single db.

Comment: It means Schema in the traditional/conceptual term as in "the shape and dialect of your DDL". JPA takes you away from the SQL specific implementation of your data store. Do not think of it too much in terms of "schema" as in part of an individual database.

Answer (score 0):

Schema independence can be achieved in the same way as DB and provider independence - it is possible to change the schema of all tables simply in configuration. You can change default schema in an orm.xml file included in persistence.xml via `persistence-unit-defaults`.

You may also specify schema via @Table annotations.

Comment: how can I provide the username and password for another schema? cause I used schema in @Table annotation it says table not found.

Comment: Within a single JPA persistence unit, you always use a single user. You cannot specify a special user to access tables within a schema. You need to assign privileges to access **all** schemas to a **single user**.

Comment: If you need to use 2 users, you may separate your entities into 2 different persistence units, but then you work with them as if they were in 2 different DBs, that meaning you have to use different entity managers and of course manipulate with them in separate transactions unless you tie the transactions together as XA transactions.